# JavaScript HTML5 Canvas Snow in 3D in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, html

I'm trying to have a snow effect on my magento site. I got a code from seb.ly which i tried on a normal html5 website and it worked, but i added it on my magento page it didn't work. 
I added it to configuration-design-footer/header on different occasions but it still didn't work aswell. Does any one have a better recommendation on getting this to work?

This is the code

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ThreeCanvas.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Snow.js"></script>
            <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight*3;
            var container;
            var particle;
            var camera;
            var scene;
            var renderer;
            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            var particles = [];
            var particleImage = new Image();//THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/ParticleSmoke.png" );
            particleImage.src = 'images/ParticleSmoke.png';
            function init() {
            container = document.createElement('div');

            document.body.appendChild(container);
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            document.getElementById("container").style.position="absolute";
            document.getElementById("container").style.margin="auto";
            document.getElementById("container").style.width="100%";
            document.getElementById("container").style.zIndex = "1"; 
            document.getElementById("container").style.marginBottom = "20px"; 
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(camera);
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.Texture(particleImage) } );
            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            particle = new Particle3D( material);
            particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 0.5;
            scene.add( particle );
            particles.push(particle);
            }
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
            setInterval( loop, 1000 / 60 );
            }
            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
            }
            function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
            }
            }
            function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
            }
            }
            //
            function loop() {
            for(var i = 0; i<particles.length; i++)
            {
            var particle = particles[i];
            particle.updatePhysics();
            with(particle.position)
            {
            if(y<-1000) y+=2000;
            if(x>1000) x-=2000;
            else if(x<-1000) x+=2000;
            if(z>1000) z-=2000;
            else if(z<-1000) z+=2000;
            }
            }
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            </scrip
```

Answer (score 0):

add js file in `base/js` folder and add your js like below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ThreeCanvas.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Snow.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Qaisar, thanks for your repsose. I've added that to my code but i still cant get it to work.

Comment: did you move ur file in `basedirectory/js/` your files

Comment: I've added the files to my base file. Just to be sure, I added it to all the templates in my installation but its not working out. Do you think it has any thing to do with the particle image link? I've added the files to my base file. Just to be sure, I added it to all the templates in my installation but its not working out. Do you think it has any thing to do with the particle image link?  
 `var particleImage = new Image();//THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/ParticleSmoke.png" );`

`particleImage.src = 'images/ParticleSmoke.png';`

Comment: did you check the console for js error?

Comment: Hi, I got this error see image  http://prntscr.com/96at8c

Comment: where you are adding the above code?

Comment: I added them to configuration-design-htmlhead-misceilenous

Comment: where is file location can you share that?

Comment: Do you mean the files for the snow effect? or do you mean where I placed those codes

Comment: both will be helpful.. because after seeing the code i think you are not placing the code in right place..

Comment: how do i send it to you? email? or dropbox

Comment: no i don't need file i need file path 

`app/design` and go on

Comment: for both javascripts - `puclic_html/js`

Comment: and file path where you adding the code?

Comment: I added it directly from the backend `configuration - design - html head - misceilenous`

Comment: update and check the console

Comment: No error in console again but its still not working

Comment: check the page source the js is loading or not?

Comment: it is loading. http://prntscr.com/96c4us

Comment: But still not working.

Comment: add image folder too in base and check it is loading image?